# How can i remove howdy from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login

I'm trying to remove howdy windows hello style login, how can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dixith:

Can you try with apt-get remove command:

```
apt-get remove howdy
```

This command remove all howdy package except the configuration files.

If you want to delete the howdy package and the configuration files, you can do:

```
apt-get purge howdy
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked.

Comment: Your welcome Dixith and welcome to askubuntu.